# FSharp.Charting and settings the major tick step

Tags: f#, fsharpchart

I am trying to use FSharp.Charting for visualisation.  However a stumbling block for me is that I am using the tutorial at Try F#, but the FSharp.Charting dll is different - has different methods signatures etc.

I am trying to translate the following line found on Try F#:

```
Chart.Point(data).WithXAxis(MajorTickStep=1.0)
```

However, I can't find a way of setting the major tick step on the X-Axis - the following code of mine does not it:

```
Chart.Point(data).WithXAxis(MajorTickMark=ChartTypes.TickMark(Interval=1.0))
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can You please, try with this chart as a simple test and tell me whether You see red tickMarks? `Chart.Point([ (0.4, 1.2); (1., 4.3); (2.2, 10.5) ]).WithYAxis(Enabled = true, MajorTickMark = ChartTypes.TickMark(Interval=1.0, LineColor = Color.Red))`

Comment: Yes, I do see red tick marks.

Comment: So it seems that the code You presented is fine, and the issue lies somewhere else. I can't help more without seeing more code.

Comment: Did You manage to find the issue?

Comment: No, could not work it out.  All I wanted is for the x-axis be 0.0 - 0.2 - 0.4 - 0.6 instead of 0.0024 - 0.2024 - 0.4024 etc - stupid that this isn't easy right?

Comment: I am able to do it using IntervalOffset, so in my example it would be: `Chart.Point([ (0.4, 1.2); (1., 4.3); (2.2, 10.5) ]).WithXAxis(MajorTickMark = ChartTypes.TickMark(Interval=1.0, IntervalOffset = 0.2, LineWidth = 2))`. Please let me know if this helps.